# Labeling Jenkins builds

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration

I would like to be able to label `Jenkins` builds so that the downstream deployment jobs only pick up the artifacts from the build that have a certain label -- not just the latest build. That would involve going into the build execution manually and labeling the build as "stable", or "prod-ready" or "uat-ready". I am using the [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) for my deployments (or war files to a web container).

Is there a Jenkins plugin that can do this or perhaps a way to do it without a new plugin installation?

Comment: A label is a resource group in Jenkins, and I'm trying to understand the term for attaching some metadata to a build which I think you want to do also @amphibent . I assume you did work out how to, please can you share your journey since?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jenkins [pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin). You can create a pipeline job with stages so after the stage of building image, next stage you can use that image for deployment. Refer documentation for more details on [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

Pipeline comes with a lot of flexibilities in which you can define the flow. You can either use a declarative pipeline or a scripted pipeline. Good number of examples can be found in [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples)

Comment: "so after the stage of building image, next stage you can use that image for deployment." -- but that's not quite what i was asking. does it allow me to